# The type or namespace session could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting error on Session.
The type or namespace session could not be found

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Context
/// </summary>
public class Context
{
    HttpContext _context;
    Session _session;

    public Context(HttpContext context, Session session)
    {
        _context = context;
        _session = session;
    }
    public bool IsLocal
    {
        get
        {
            return _context.Request.Url.ToString().Contains("localhost");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Session` isn't in the `System` or `System.Linq` namespaces. It's somewhere else. You need to either fully qualify the class name or add another using statement.

Comment: Fun fact: hit `Ctrl+.` while over any line with `Session` and a menu will come up to help you add the missing using statement.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to access session using context object session property `context.Session` which is an instance of `HttpSessionState` class defined in `System.Web` namespace.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate?view=netframework-4.8